# Virtual memory and Heap

Tags: c, memory, malloc, virtual-memory, low-level

Good morning. I hope some can help me out understanding how one aspect of virtual memory works and how C behaves.
From what I understand, whenever we call `malloc`, C will add it to the heap, with the pointers going upwards. If the stack and the heap bump on each other, `malloc` will return NULL, since there is no more memory to work with.
[image: Virtual memory map]

What I do not understand is the fact that the Virtual memory of each program is seized when we call it, and the low and high adresses of the runing script itself are determined. This way, the program has a fixed amount of memory to use. Is the heap growing with the data *on it*, or the heap is actually just a set of pointers to the actuall data? If the program has a fixed memory at the begin (because it can´t have all the memory) for me it does not make sense to store the raw data in the heap, or else we easily would get out of available memory. What am I missing?

Comment: That diagram is out of date, and doesn't apply to systems with virtual memory.

Comment: @user3386109 The diagram is perfectly OK. It shows virtual memory of a single process.

Comment: A virtual memory manager typically fakes it such that each process thinks it has all the memory in the world, from address 0x0 to address 0xFFF...FFF (whatever is your address space width). Of course there isn't that much memory on most computers, let alone that much for every process. The OS maps chunks of physical memory (maybe called pages or segments) to whatever chunks of the virtual address space the process actually uses. I am simplifying, but only a little bit.

Comment: The "fixed amount of memory" is the entire virtual address space, or the low half of it for a 64-bit process on a 64-bit kernel (rather than 32 on 64 where the 32-bit process can have a whole 4GiB).

Comment: @n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m. Thanks for your clarification. I think it now makes more sense!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making several incorrect assumptions. The most important one being that you program has one chunk of memory assigned to it that starts at address x and goes to address x + program size. This is not so, your program is divided into chunks (different platforms give them different names). The stack will be one, the heap may be several, the code will be in several etc.

When the heap manager runs out of its current chunk it can simply get another one.

Also note that this has nothing to do with 'virtual memory'.